# Headset mic too low only on Macbook

Tags: headphones, microphone

I have a Macbook Pro (2017, 15-inch) running macOS 10.13.6. I am trying to use a [new headset](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LFVSKRS) in it but the mic's volume is too low.  This problem does not appear when using the headset with my phone (an Android) not does it appear with other microphones (I have tried both cheap and expensive headsets and not had this issue).

I can confirm that the mic is being picked up by the machine and that the system settings has the external input set to the highest volume.

Is there a way to increase the input volume for the microphone beyond just the system settings?

Comment: I assume you've gone to system preferences/sound and checked the microphone input option??

Comment: @jmh Correct. That's what I meant about the system settings.

Comment: Thats what I thought but wanted to check first. Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

Connect and disconnect the headset, until the microphone volume is fine. My best guess is that the Macbook "decides" what's the microphone's sensitivity when you connect it, and then it stays constant at the hardware level.